# Do AWS EC2 Launch Template resource tags take precedence over Autoscaling Group (ASG) tags?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

When launching an Autoscaling Group (ASG) launches an instance and has a "Name" tag defined and the ASG is using a Launch Template that has a "Name" resource tag defined, which Name tag is used to tag the new instance, the ASG "Name" tag or the Launch Template "Name" tag?

Answer (score 1):

If the Autoscaling Group (ASG) "Name" tag has "Tag new instances" checked/true then new instances will use the ASG "Name" tag even if there is a "Name" resource tag on the Launch Template.

If the ASG "Tag new instances" is unchecked/false then the new instances will use the Launch Template "Name" tag.

The screenshot below shows the ASG "Name" tag unset for "Tag new instances" so that the Launch Template resource tag "Name" will take precedence over the ASG "Name" tag.

[image: AWS EC2 Autoscaling Group screenshot showing the "Tag new instances" checkbox on the tags]

source: This is undocumented in my searching but I figured it out by trial and error.